# How to install LaTeX class on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, django-templates, latex, pdflatex

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku. In it, I am using a view written in LaTeX to generate a pdf on-the-fly, and have installed the Heroku [LaTeX buildpack](https://github.com/gulopine/heroku-buildpack-tex) to get this to work. My LaTeX view is below.

```
def pdf(request):
    context = {}
    template = get_template('cv/cv.tex')
    rendered_tpl = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')  
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        process = Popen(
            ['pdflatex', '-output-directory', tempdir],
            stdin=PIPE,
            stdout=PIPE,
        )
        out, err = process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
           pdf = f.read()
    r = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')  
    r.write(pdf)
    return r
```

This works fine when I use one of the existing document classes in `cv.tex` (eg. `\documentclass{article}`), but I would like to use a custom one, called [`res`](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/res.cls). Ordinarily I believe there are two options for using a custom class.

1. Place the class file (`res.cls`, in this case) in the same folder as the `.tex` file. For me, that would be in the templates folder of my app. I have tried this, but `pdflatex` cannot find the class file. (Presumably because it is not running in the templates folder, but in a temporary directory? Would there be a way to copy the class file to the temporary directory?)
2. Place the class file inside another folder with the structure `localtexmf/tex/latex/res.cls`, and make `pdflatex` aware of it using the method outlined in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex). I've tried running the CLI instructions on Heroku using `heroku run bash`, but it does not recognise `initexmf`, and I'm not entirely sure how to specify a relevant directory.

How can I tell `pdflatex` where to find to find the class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding [another workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358693/can-a-class-file-be-merged-into-a-tex-file) to achieve my goal, but the most straightforward solution I found would be to change `TEXMFHOME` at runtime, for example...

```
TEXMFHOME=/d pdflatex <filename>.tex
```

...if you had `/d/tex/latex/res/res.cls`.

Credit goes to [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) on tex.stackexchange.com for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just 2 ideas, I don't know if it'll solve your problems.

First, try to put your `localtexmf` folder in `~/texmf` which is the default local folder in Linux systems (I don't know much about Heroku but it's mostly Linux systems, right?).

Second, instead of using `initexmf`, I usually use `texhash`, it may be available on your system?